# Android KSOAP with .Net Web Service

Tags: c#, android, ksoap2

I have created web service using .Net C#. Now I am trying to access this from android app so I tried using KSOAP2.

This is my code.

```
final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
final String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";
final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";
final String URL = "http://localhost:61252/Service1.asmx"; 

new Thread() {

 public void run() {
                     SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                     SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                     SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                     envelope.dotNet=true;
                     envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                     HttpTransportSE  httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                     httpTransport.debug = true;
                     try {
                      httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                      SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

                     }
                     catch (Exception e) {
                         // TODO: handle exception
                    }}}.start();
```

But in this line

```
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

It is going into catch block and do not have any error message.

I also found so many questions regarding this but as i am new to this not able to find where i am going wrong.

Am I doing correct or is there any other method which i can use?

Comment: in catch write this line `e.printStackTrace();` and do let us know which error log it shows.

Comment: try to debug it and set breakpoints in try as well as catch block. and check your response or exception and provide log's to us.

Comment: Thanks, I tried e.printStackTrace() problem was with internet connection, did not added the uses-permission for internet now it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);        
     SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
     envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

     HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
     ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
     final  SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
     final String str = response.toString();
```

use this for your [reference](http://codeoncloud.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-403-webservice-access-tutorial.html). Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks..The reference that you have given was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
// if required you can use addProperty to add properties in url
            request.addProperty("User", "abcd@gmail.com");
            request.addProperty("Password", "abcd");
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.headerOut = new Element[1];
            envelope.headerOut[0] = buildAuthHeader();
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            // if you want to add any property you can add here.

            /*
             * PropertyInfo cityProp = new PropertyInfo();
             * 
             * cityProp.setType(String.class); request.addProperty(cityProp);
             */

            Log.e("value of request", request.toString());
            Log.e("Value of envolope ", envelope.toString());

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    // add try catch block.
            try {

                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                Log.i("myAppEnvelope", envelope.toString());

                SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
    // There are two types of Soap response (as per my knowledge or use )
    // SoapObject or SoapPrimitive  so check what is your response and use accordingly.

    SoapObject data = (SoapObject) response
                        .getProperty("field_name");

    // OR 

    SoapPrimitive data = (SoapPrimitive) data.getProperty("field_name");
```